# how to delete a subview (button) in table view if segment controller is changed?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

the problem that i'm facing is that i have segmented controller in UItable view , selecting index 0 , it suppose to shows buttons( and its working perfectly). the problem is when i select index 1 and the table view changed its contents , the buttons here should all be deleted . if i add these statement, it only delete the button in the last cell

### these statement just delete the button of the last cell

```
        [cell willRemoveSubview:downloadButton];
        [downloadButton removeFromSuperview];
        downloadButton.hidden=YES;
```

---

```
-(void)configureCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
    [downloadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(250,8,30,30)];
    [downloadButton setTag :indexPath.row];
    [downloadButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DownloadLesson.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButton:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (segOL.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        [cell addSubview:downloadButton];
    } else {
        [cell willRemoveSubview:downloadButton];
        [downloadButton removeFromSuperview];
        downloadButton.hidden=YES;
    }
}
- (IBAction)cellButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton *play = sender;   
    NSLog(@"Number of row %d", play.tag]);
}
```

Comment: plz watch your code formatting the future. makes it awfully hard to read :-)

Answer (score 0):

downloadButton is never added to the view when you call removefromsuperview. It is made anew everytime you use the cell. **Buttons keep piling up**

you have to save the old button and not make a new one and forgetting the old :)

e.g.:

```
@interface CellClass : UITableViewCell {
    UIButton *downloadButton;
}

...

-(void)configureCell: (UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(!downloadButton) {
        downloadButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
        [downloadButton setFrame:CGRectMake(250,8,30,30)];
        [downloadButton setTag :indexPath.row];
        [downloadButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DownloadLesson.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [downloadButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cellButton:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }        
    if (segOL.selectedSegmentIndex==0) {
        [cell addSubview:downloadButton];
    } else {
        [cell willRemoveSubview:downloadButton];
        [downloadButton removeFromSuperview];
        downloadButton.hidden=YES;
    }
}
- (IBAction)cellButton:(id)sender {

    UIButton *play = sender;

    NSLog(@"Number of row %d", play.tag]);
}
```

Comment: if i do this, the button shows in the last cell in both segmented views

Comment: well you have a mistake in some part of the code not shown to us then :). this correctly adds a button to the cell.

Comment: i have segmented controller in UItable view , selecting index 0 , it suppose to shows buttons( and its working perfectly). the problem is when i select index 1 and the table view changed its contents , the buttons here should all be deleted . if i add these statement, it only delete the button in the last cell 
         [cell willRemoveSubview:downloadButton];
        [downloadButton removeFromSuperview];
        downloadButton.hidden=YES